# Testing iOS In-App Purchase with Ad-Hoc Version of App

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-App purchase for a set of premium features for the next version of an App that is already available in the App Store. I have tested IAP from my device, using XCode to launch the App, and everything works.

Before submitting Apps to Apple I normally distribute Ad-Hoc copies to a number of QA users for thorough testing.

My question: Can those users test IAP the same way I do, i.e., going through the Sandbox with the test user I configured with iTunes Connect, or this only works when the App is launched from XCode?

Answer (score 5):

Yes they can, but they need to sign out of their current account first and NOT log in with the new one until they are in your app and trying to purchase something.

Comment: not working for me on iOS 7.1 in an app compiled for 7.0